# My laptop temperature is too high on idle

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, overheating

I have an Asus x507ub laptop with i7 8550u, and 8gigs of ram

My laptop sometimes reaches temperatures of 100c but nothing really happens:

[image]

I am wondering if this could this damage my laptop over time, and what the possible causes of this problem could be?

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

> and what are possible causes of this problem?

If you're under warranty, get it fixed. If you're not under warranty, and either you don't want to risk the machine or you're not confident, take it to a professional. If you are confident in fixing it yourself then it could be one of two problems:

```
Your thermal paste is kaput.
```

I recently repasted my gaming laptop since I was experiencing temps of 90C at idle. Buy some high quality thermal paste, and find a teardown guide or [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5WTYzdR7sI), clean your dyes, repaste, reassemble. I used thermalright's TF8 which was only about £10 on amazon. Beats paying someone else for their time, or buying a new machine. Temps went to 60C under load.

```
Your fans, or cooling system is kaput.
```

Best case scenario, your laptop is gunked up. Disassemble, clean, reassemble. Worst case scenario, you have broken parts. In that case, you need to find spare parts online that fit your model of laptop. It's not impossible, and with some googlfu you will surely find your answers. It will be a case of unplugging the fan, and placing in a new one.

> could this damage my laptop over time?

Yes! Your CPU's max operating temperature is 100C. You do not want to run your hardware at its max rated temperature. This will drastically shorten its lifespan.

Your temps are sitting at 100C because your CPU is undervolting to stop it from destroying itself.

Comment: thank you so much,i will go and try that.
about the cleaning part i already opened my laptop and cleaned it, and there is no broken parts as far as i know.

Comment: Good answer. I like the formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Your cpu fan is not working, or the fan needs cleaning. Either you can open your laptop to see what's going on or if you are still in warranty take it back to your dealer, cause it's sure that it will harm your cpu

Comment: i did open and clean it , and the fan is working.
could the temp sensor be broken ?
cause I don't feel that much heat under it